# Unit Test all IEntity with IRepositories

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics

We have approximately 300 POCO objects each of which inherits from an IEntity interface.  Within our service layer we have an IRepository and also a DbContext with all the EntityTypeConfigurations specified for each POCO class.

We are trying to unit test these to ensure the mappings are correct.  Is there a way we can call our helper method below automatically for all IEntity objects in the assembly.

```
    internal static void TestRepositoryForEntity<T>(T obj) where T : class, IEntity
    {
      ILogger logger = new Logging.NLog.NLogLogger(null);
      IConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new ConnectionProvider(logger);

      IEntityRepository<T> testRepo = new BaseEntityRepository<T>(connectionProvider);

      var allResults = testRepo.GetAll();
      foreach (var item in allResults)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
      }
    }
```

Currently we call it like this:

```
Helpers.EntityContextHelper.TestRepositoryForEntity(new Zinc.Entities.User());
```

However if I try and get all the IEntity objects and pass those over the T type in the helper is IEntity and the mappings are not found for the right type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems slightly strange to pass an instance of the object as a parameter; why not remove it and just call `TestRespositoryForEntity<Zinc.Entities.User>()`. (What if a type is abstract?) Regardless of that; if you have an assembly somewhere you can call the generic methods like this:

```
var assembly = typeof (User).Assembly;

var typeList = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract 
    && typeof (IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(t));

MethodInfo testMethodInfo =
    typeof (Helpers.EntityContextHelper)
    .GetMethod("TestRepositoryForEntity").GetGenericMethodDefinition();


foreach (var type in typeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Checking type {0}", type.FullName);
    //we need an instance;
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    //create the correct generic method:
    var testMethodToCall = testMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
    //invoke
    testMethodToCall.Invoke(null, new [] { instance });
}
```